# Laravel 5.5 - MethodNotAllowedHttpException when using POST method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I created filter to get data from database. When I use GET method it works but with POST method I get error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

I spent hours looking for solution but seems like I am missing something here.

For test I tried to get results directly in routes but it's still same problem.

This works.

```
<?php
use App\test;
Route::get('/', function () {
    $test = test::all();
return $test;
});
```

This doesn't work.

```
<?php
use App\test;
Route::post('/', function () {
    $test = test::all();
return $test;
});
```

Comment: try clearing your cache `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @FuzzyTree It doesn't help.

Comment: how are you testing the post? are you actually creating a post request or are you testing it the same way as the get?

Comment: Share the code from where you are calling get or post ?

Comment: I am testing it same way and there is no other code, just empty class. I have same error with this example:                           Route::post('foo/bar', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});

Comment: Are you submitting your data through Form? Or if you need both get and post method you should use Route::method(['get', 'post']) , '/', function () {
    $test = test::all();
    return $test;
});

Answer (score 2):

This

```
use App\test;
Route::post('/', function () {
    $test = test::all();
return $test;
});
```

Should always be an instance of `Request` so you can't access it directly in the browser like `GET` you have to post some form data to it. So it's better you rename it to something, maybe like:

```
use App\test;

Route::post('/test', function (Request $request) {
    $test = test::all();
return $test;
});
```

This `$request` hold your form data

Answer (score 2):

`Route::get()` and `Route::post()` are defining the route handlers for the specified http methods.

If you only define this route:

```
Route::post('/', function () {
    $test = test::all();
    return $test;
});
```

Then you must make sure all calls to that url use the POST method. If you make a request to that url with the GET method, you'll get the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` exception, since you only defined the POST method handler.

Answer (score 1):

It's look like you may forgot about  {{ csrf_field() }}. Add this to your form.

If you are posting data without the csrf, in laravel 5.5 you will see this error.

Comment: `@csrf` is also valid because of blade template engine

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you are writing the route for post, when testing it make sure that your are posting the data to the page otherwise it will through an error.

Post routes cannot test simply by calling the url, the method should be post. If you check the route URI using postman it will work.